# Click() method doesn’t work respectively to input file form on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mobile-website

Code from index.html

```
<body>

    <form action="upload.php" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px; opacity: 0;" method="post" target="hiddenframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="hideBtn();"> 

        <input type="file" id="uploadnewimg" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px" name="userfile" /> 

        <input type="submit" name="upload" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px" id="uploadbutton" value="Загрузить" /> 

        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" /> 

    </form> 

    <div id="res"></div> 

    <iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe" style="width:0px;     height:0px; border:0px"></iframe>

</body>
```

Javascript generates div, which when is touched runs the next code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("uploadnewimg");
input.click();
```

Next, on desktops appear a choose-file dialog, but on safari ios13 and chrome android 5 just nothing happens.

How to fix it? What I need is when the div is clicked the choose-file dialog should appear, and after choosing, the file automatically is sending on sever(it works fine)

**Updated**

Seems it’s just impossible(end of the article) https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: this looks like a security feature of the browser..... The js "click" in considered "untrusted" by the browser, because it wasn't in response to user input.

Comment: @dovidweisz, I tested it on ios at first, so I thought it’s impossible at all to send any file on ios, but when i touch it directly, it works, and I can send any file.

Comment: Exactly. Because that event is trusted.

Comment: @dovidweisz, can’t believe that nothing can be done to solve my problem..